# Last letter is input + 1 for some reason

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, char, scanf

I'm doing an exercise to print 3 letters taken from the user. The first two letters end up fine, but the last one is always the letter that comes after what the user inputs for some reason (I've tried a few different combinations of inputs and it's always the same result):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    char userChar[3];
    int i;

    for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++){
        printf("Enter letter %d\n", i);
        scanf(" %c", &userChar[i]);
    }

    printf("%c %c %c", userChar[1], userChar[2], userChar[3]);

    return 0;
}
```

The input is: abc
The output is: abd

What did I screw up? Thanks for your help!

*Edit* made recommended changes but still not working

[image]

[image]

Comment: Arrays in C are `0` based. I.e. the first element is `userChar[0]` and the last one is `userChar[2]`.

Comment: So `userChar[3]` is breaking the array bounds and the result could be anything - from the wrong answer to a crash.

Comment: Still produced the same result

Comment: `for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)` and then `userChar[0], userChar[1], userChar[2]`

Comment: tried that as well and still produced the same result unfortunately

Comment: That can't be. You are doing something wrong. Not saving the file, not compiling or something like that.

Comment: Saved and compiled, still same result

Comment: Please show your updated code *in addition* to the existing one in the question. You can [edit] your question.

Comment: Re the update: you changed the array length from `char userChar[3];` to `char userChar[2];`

Comment: Well, I suspected it... It's indices who are zero based, but not the length. Keep it `3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll post this as an answer just to clarify the amendments

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    char userChar[3];
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){                                    // the loop range
        printf("Enter letter %d\n", i + 1);                     // for human use
        scanf(" %c", &userChar[i]);
    }
    printf("%c %c %c", userChar[0], userChar[1], userChar[2]);  // the array indexing

    return 0;
}
```

Program session

```
Enter letter 1
a
Enter letter 2
b
Enter letter 3
c
a b c
```

Comment: Awesome that works thanks! It worked when I changed the array size from 2 to 3, is that just a general rule of thumb to leave extra space in arrays?

Comment: It's not an extra! When you define `char userChar[3];` it's an array of *three* elements. Don't confuse the size with the indexing. Array of three elements is indexed with `0` through `2`.